# Lotus Notes - @Subset function - get the last element

Tags: view, lotus-notes, subset

I'm trying to find out how to get the last position from a list obtained from

```
@Unique ( @DbLookup( "" : "NoCache" ; @DbName ; _view ; field1+field2 ; 2 ));
```

This gives me a list containing , let say , 5 elements. ( I don't know always how much elements there are in it ).

I just to get the last element ( from last position ) ! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the answer is in your question's title itself. You can use the `@Subset` function to do that. So your code would be:

```
list := @Unique ( @DbLookup( "" : "NoCache" ; @DbName ; _view ; field1+field2 ; 2 ));
lastElement :=  @Subset(list; -1);
```

The help documentation says that: *If you specify a negative number, `@Subset` searches the list from right to left, but the result is ordered as from the beginning of the list.*

Comment: Naveen, thanks for your help! It worked, but now I need something else based on what I did with your help

Comment: @PhaulGuen: I would suggest you to create a new question for this. The edit to your question has made it entirely different which would make its answers irrelevant.